# Behavior of $MinPrecision seems to have changed between 12.0.0 and 12.1.1

Tags: warning-messages, precision-and-accuracy, version-12.1

I am running into a very weird bug where setting `$MinPrecision` to some value (in this case `200`) has a very different and undesirable effect in Mathematica 12.1.1 compared to what I was used to in 12.0.0.

To illustrate take the following code:

```
$MinPrecision = 200;
RunProcess[{"bash", "-c", "echo grgr"}, "StandardOutput"]
```

It will produce many instances of the `SetPrecision::precsm` error while it never did before. I am not sure whether I can simply silence and ignore these errors or whether they are indicating a serious problem. What is going on here? Can I just silence all `SetPrecision::precsm` errors and assume things work like they did before?

(I am now using "12.1.1 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2020)" and was using
"12.0.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)" before.)

Comment: The errors probably don't matter, but could you run `Block[{$MinPrecision = 0}, RunProcess[{"bash", "-c", "echo grgr"}, "StandardOutput"]]` instead?  (BTW, I don't get all kinds of errors, only one error multiple times.)

Comment: @MichaelE2, good point it is `SetPrecision::precsm` multiple times. I'll edit it. (The only other error is `General::stop` since the above error occured many times.) Well `$MinPrecision` is there for a reason. Putting all elements that don't require it inside a block kind of defies its existence. Note that the same error also occurs for other things I believe. This was just a convenient small example where clearly there should not be any reason for this error.